# Why is the value of a variable (var1) being changed when I change the value of another variable (var2) that I previously had assigned it to (var2=var1

Tags: python

I am creating a list, x, and assigning another variable b to x. When I change the value of the first item in b, it is also changing the value of the first item in x.

This is the code I am executing.

```
x = [1]
b = x
b[0] = 2
print(x)
```

It is printing '[2]'

I expected the value of x to remain unchanged. I thought the code would print '[1]'

Comment: `b=x` doesn't make a copy, it just gives you two different ways to refer to the same list object.

Comment: because `b` and `x` *are referring to the same list object*. That is what `b = x` *does*. Check out: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html